# Null pointer Exception in Testng annotations

Tags: java, selenium, testng

can any one tell me why im getting **NullPointerException** for the 2nd method, if I only write one method and execute it not getting any exception, below is the code, your support is really appreciated-:

```
public class Test1234 {

    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testsetup() throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.gmail.co.in");
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();

        File src=new File("./read1.properties");
        FileInputStream sd=new FileInputStream(src);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Properties pr=new Properties();
        pr.load(sd);
        String usern=pr.getProperty("username");
        System.out.println(usern);

        driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys(usern);

    }
    @Test
    public void drr() 
    {

        driver.getTitle();
        String s=driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(s, s, "pass");
        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

Comment: you forgot to initialize driver

Answer (score 1):

In TestNG you can use [@BeforeTest](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) annotation on a method to initialize objects as `driver` for all tests:

```
@BeforeTest
public void init() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver=new ChromeDriver();

}
```

> @BeforeTest: The annotated method will be run before any test method belonging to the classes inside the  tag is run.